# Liferay SSO with NTLM

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, ntlm, autologin

I have Liferay 5.2.3 running in an intranet and users will be logged into their pcs with their domain account. They are also logging in to Liferay with the same credentials and my liferay is programmed to communicate with my LDAP server for authentication. I want to know if it is possible to implement autologin feature where whenever the user opens the page, he/she should log in automatically to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure NTLM in Liferay.

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integration+with+NTLM+plus+ADS